# Machine goes hang while running cron job with 1 minutes duration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, cron, whenever

I am new to Rails, I am using **whenever** to gem to run cron job.In my application, I have some jobs that can be performed by drivers.The jobs has start and end time and it can be assigned to drivers.By cron job I need to check some conditions, like a

```
1. job is assigned and start within 30 minutes.
2. job is unassigned and start within 30 minutes.
3. job is assigned and start within 15 minutes.
```

I added the conditions to .rake file and mentioned the jobs in schedule file, below I paste my code snippets.

schedule.rb

```
every 1.minutes do
  rake "jobs:unassigned_job_start_in_30"
end

every 1.minutes do
  rake "jobs:assigned_job_start_in_30"
end

every 1.minutes do
  rake "jobs:assigned_job_start_in_15"
end
```

and my rake file 
auto_expire.rake

```
desc "assigned job starts in 30 mins."
task :assigned_job_start_in_30 => :environment do
start_range = Time.now.utc.to_time.to_i+(CONFIG[:job_starts_in_time_30]*60)
end_range   = start_range + (1*60)
jobs = Job.where("start_at >= :start_range AND start_at <= :end_range AND status =:status", {start_range: start_range.to_s, end_range: end_range.to_s, status: 2000} )
  jobs.each do |job|
    job.add_event_log(nil, 2054)
      create_and_send_notification(2054, job.id, 0, nil)
    end
  end

desc "assigned job starts in 15 mins."
task :assigned_job_start_in_15 => :environment do
start_range = Time.now.utc.to_time.to_i+    (CONFIG[:job_starts_in_time_15]*60)
end_range   = start_range + (1*60)
jobs = Job.where("start_at >= :start_range AND start_at <=  :end_range AND status =:status", {start_range: start_range.to_s,     end_range: end_range.to_s, status: 2000} )
jobs.each do |job|
  job.add_event_log(nil, 2055)
    create_and_send_notification(2055, job.id, 0, nil)
  end
end
```

As the cron jobs performed with 1 minutes duration, so my machine goes hang.Please suggest me what is the best way to check the conditions and performed cron jobs.

Answer (score 0):

The cron jobs should run in the background, so your machine shouldn't hang while running it, there might be other reasons this is happening.

An alternative, is to just have one single task that runs, that checks and creates the tasks for a separate system that runs it. One example would be [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq).